# insert dynamic template that uses ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS(v 1.28) ng-repeat directive to list a bunch of users, as can seen in the code below.  Some users can see the status(on or off) of the users account in the column titled Account mode.  Other users(Admins) should see a set of radio buttons that show the current status of the account but also allow them to change the status.  All the information needed to determine what the user should see is in  `$scope.groups`.  The code below provides what I expect on the screen but the ng-click function never seems to be called(this is the problem).  I have looked around and it seems to be the issue is I have to call compile on the strings?  Howevere when I do this and `return $sce.trustAsHtml($compile(controlHtml));`  I dont see anything on the screen.  I have also looked at directives but it doesn't seem clear to me how to use them in this case.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62cg2usn/1/).

NOTE:
When I attempted this `return $sce.trustAsHtml($compile(controlHtml));`
I did inject `$compile`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="usersController">
    <table ng-show="group.expanded">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Created</th>
                <th>Modified</th>
                <th>Account Mode</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in groups.users">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>{{user.dateCreated | dateFormat}}</td>
                <td>{{user.dateUpdated | dateFormat}}</td>
                <td ng-bind-html="getUserModeHtml(user,group.isAdmin)"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.
module("userLibrary").
controller("usersController", function ($scope, $filter,$sce, userGroups) {
    "use strict";

     $scope.groups = userGroups;

     $scope.getUserModeHtml = function (user,isAdmin) {
        var controlHtml;

        if(isInternalUser){

            if (user.isLocked) {
                controlHtml = "<input type='radio' name='userMode-" + user.id + "' value='on' ng-click='toggleUserModeMode(user)' >On<input type='radio' name='-" + user.id + "' value='off'  ng-click='toggleUserMode(user)' checked='checked'>Off";
            } else {
                controlHtml = "<input type='radio' name='userMode-" + user.id + "' value='on'  ng-click='toggleUserMode(user)' checked='checked'>On<input type='radio' name='UserMode-" + user.id + "'  ng-click='toggleUserMode(user)' value='off'>Off";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            controlHtml = user.isLocked ? "On" : "Off";
        }

        return $sce.trustAsHtml(controlHtml);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use $compile provider and make directive for compiling custom html

```
app.directive('htmlBinder', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,

    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.htmlBinder, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62cg2usn/2/

Comment: Using that example I got this error: Attempted to trust a non-string value in a content requiring a string: Context: html

Comment: could you try whithot trustAsHtml ? because its already trusted content

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/isecdom I still end up getting an error, It seems its frowned upon to try to return a DOM node from a controller

Comment: could you bring it in fiddle ?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/62cg2usn/1/) Here is a fiddle as I have it now, without the changes you suggested